# ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to write the following code but I get the error message:  "ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq."
I have no idea of how to fix it? I tried to google on the error message but couldn't find any case similar to mine.

df is a python pandas dataframe for which I want to create new columns showing the daily change. The code is shown below. How can I fix the code to avoid the value error?

```
for column_names in df:
        df[column_names+'%-daily'] =df[column_names].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Is 1 a valid argument to pct_change?  I thought you had to pass it a date offset, or a string representing one minute or one day, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had date as index. Since only weekdays were shown delta became incorrect. When I changed to period.

```
for column_names in list(df.columns.values):
        df[column_names+'%-daily'] =df[column_names].pct_change(periods=1).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, instead of `df.index.shift()`, I had to use `pd.Series(df.index).shift()`.

Overall, I used it as below:

```
df['index_diff'] = (df.index - pd.Series(df.index).shift()).values
```